# Is there a way to use a JavaScript file like this in React.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, public

How do I use an external jQuery file like this in my React.js?

```
        (function ($) {
  // "use strict";

  // Dropdown on mouse hover
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function toggleNavbarMethod() {
      if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(".navbar .dropdown")
          .on("mouseover", function () {
            $(".dropdown-toggle", this).trigger("click");
          })
          .on("mouseout", function () {
            $(".dropdown-toggle", this).trigger("click").blur();
          });
      } else {
        $(".navbar .dropdown").off("mouseover").off("mouseout");
      }
    }
    toggleNavbarMethod();
    $(window).resize(toggleNavbarMethod);
  });
```

I have got a static HTML page using this and it is working fine.

Comment: why would you want this? you can do all this in react

Comment: i have the static page ready already just doing the conversion

Comment: React handles DOM changes for you, so also letting jQuery do that is really not a good idea. If you just want a "quick fix" you could make two separate html pages, where the jQuery page does not use React.